What is affective spirituality?
In St Augustine's Confessions (Book X, Chapter 27) we read:

Late have I loved you, beauty so old and so new: late have I loved You. And see, You were within and I was in the external world and sought You there, and in my unlovely state I plunged into those lovely created things which You made. You were with me, and I was not with You. The lovely things kept me far from you, though if they did not have their existence in you, they had no existence at all. You called and cried out loud and shattered my deafness. You were radiant and resplendent, You put to flight my blindness. You were fragrant, and I drew in my breath and now pant after You. I tasted You, and I feel but hunger and thirst for You. You touched me, and I am set on fire to attain the peace which is Yours.
Edition used: Saint Augustine Confessions: A new translation by Henry Chadwick (1991, Reissued as Oxford World's Classics Paperbacks in 1998).

I know that some people can't read it without feeling like crying.
This text doesn't move me at all. I just don't understand it.
I have heard about the term "affective spirituality" and that St Augustine represented one version of it.
Fr. John Hardon's Modern Catholic Dictionary entry on "Affections" says:

A broad variety of human sentiments that are distinguished from strictly mental or cognitive experiences. Affections pertain to the will, desires, and feelings, i.e., the outgoing activities.  In the spiritual life they are identified with those movements of the soul that reach out to God and with the invisible world of angels and saints. Affections are acts of the infused virtues of hope and charity. (Etym. Latin affectus, condition, situation; affectionate state or inclination; faculty of desire.)

This definition mentions feelings, so perhaps this kind of spirituality has a lot to do with them.  It could also mean that it focuses a lot more on feeling than on thinking, instead of giving them equal importance.
What is affective spirituality?

I cannot find any link between "affective spirituality" and St. Augustine.  What I found originated in the late Middle Ages, centuries after St. Augustine.  Perhaps you could provide a reference where you heard of it?

I don't have a specific source for my statement but my understanding from listening to people is that the Confessions are written with an emphasis on the affectice rather than the intellectual. I find him difficult because of his emphasis on the affective. I can't relate to him because of it.

The text on that website was a bit strange. It didn't even mention St bernard and other people who are famous for what we call the affective spirituality.

Jonathan Edwards wrote a well known book The Religious Affections on the topic (from a Protestant perspective, but much of it would be the same in Catholicism.)

We need to be careful when investigating a terminology that contain a commonly used word (such as "affections") because usually it has acquired a more specific meaning.  I think "affections" is more closely related to "passion" / "desire" coming from built-in human nature, something we experience as "coming from outside" rather than "emotion" that we feel as "resulting from inside activities".  A similar term is "sensibility" (a title of Jane Austen's book) whose meaning is no longer common today but refers to a combination of "passion" and "emotion" today.

"The Confessions was written with an emphasis on the affective rather than the intellectual" St. Augustine for sure IS NOT a modern enlightenment-philosophy-affected person (sorry for the pun) who de-emphasize or even eliminate desires & emotion out of rationality. He, like Aquinas his medieval successor, is more well rounded, who interpreted the famous St. Augustine's dictum: "Our hearts are restless till they find their rest in Thee", another quote from Confessions, as including the intellectual, since Aquinas poses a key category of the human psyche he named "intellectual desire".
